# Should a subordinate CA appear under the Trusted Root CA?

Tags: certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

Recently I needed to setup PKI for VDI solution as smart card functionality was needed to handle SSO with Azure. I configured an offline Root CA and a domain joined subordinate CA per MS instructions and other guides. While working with support from the vendor to resolve some issues with smart card, the vendor used dspublish commands to manually populate the RootCA value of both my offline root and my subordinate (Long story short is that policy was configured unknown to me to stop automatic enrollment so my CA wasn't propagating, found this out much later and corrected). They may have run dspublish to something else besides RootCA but I can't recall.

As things stand now, everything is working but where I see the certs on my machine and servers don't seem right. Even if things are working, I'd like to make sure what I have is either fine or I should make attempts to clean this up before we use the CA for anything additional.

Right now, my subordinate CA and my Root CA both appear in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities and Intermediate Certification Authorities container on my machine (Specifically under the Enterprise physical store in both locations.) This does not seem right to me, I would expect my Sub to be in the intermediate only and the root only in the root. I've been looking for a way to clean this up but I can't seem to find what I am looking for besides ripping it all out and starting over from scratch OR is this a non issue?

Comment: Typically the issuing CA is only in the Intermediate store, yes. That isn't a Microsoft or Windows thing. How does this devolve to "ripping it all out"?

Comment: I don't know a way to cleanup what I currently have. Since my Root and Sub are appearing in both physical stores, I'm not exactly sure what to do to have my intermediate CA only appear in that store and my root only in my root. I'm quite positive the vendor used dspublish to push my intermediate into my RootCA, I believe the command was this: certutil.exe -dspublish -f <certfilename> RootCA. I think he also put both in the SubCA value as well. Is there a way to remove those items once they have been published? If not, since its a very fresh build, starting from scratch is an option.

Comment: `certutil -dspublish` stores the certificate in an LDAP attribute in the Configuration partition under:CN=Configuration ..., CN=Services, CN=Public Key Services, CN=Certificate Authorities.  https://dimitri.janczak.net/2020/12/11/publishing-certificates-in-the-active-directory/

Comment: My cert values are located in my registry here: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates, different from what the article you posted states. That being said, I've seen the items in ADSI edit in that location but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue/what is safe to delete. I have both CA's information under the Certificate Authorities and AIA. OR to clear, is this really even an issue?

Comment: It seems like you see certificates, delete them, and they return and you are unable to identify the source? Could be Group Policy. Or a script running somewhere. There may also be events in the application log, and you should enable the CAPI2 event log, it usually has some information. I've never had a problem with duplicate authority certs in the wrong store though.

Answer (score 0):

Having both the Root CA and Subordinate CA in both the Trusted Root Certification Authorities and Intermediate Certification Authorities containers is not best practice . It's generally expected that the Root CA is in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities container, and the Subordinate CA is in the Intermediate Certification Authorities container.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. Since the setup was so early in its creation/usage I went into ADSI and manually removed everything in these locations:

CN=Certification Authorities,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=...

CN=AIA,Authorities,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=...

That flushed the values from reappearing in the enterprise physical store on my devices. After that I manually republished my sub authority ensuring it was only set to "SubCA" and it didn't recreate the value under the Certification Authorities container only AIA, only showing under Intermediate now. The Root is now only being pushed through GPO now instead. Essentially the mess was indeed caused by the vendors dspublish actions of both certs into both stores.